# CSS: Replicate Bootstrap class table-sm and apply to mobile screens only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4, media

I use **Bootstrap 4** to create a table that starts as below. 
Bootstrap has a built-in class `"table-sm"` that minimises padding (and maybe something else) to make tables fit better on small screens.

When I apply this class in the below example instead of `"table-custom"` it works as intended but I would like to apply this on mobile (small) screens only. 
I therefore created a class `"table-custom"` and used the below CSS but I can't get this to work.

Can someone tell me what else I have to do to r**eplicate the `"table-sm"` class and limit it to mobile (small) screens only** ?

**My HTML (start):**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-custom table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
```

**My CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-custom>thead>tr>th, 
    .table-custom>thead>tr>td, 
    .table-custom>tbody>tr>th, 
    .table-custom>tbody>tr>td, 
    .table-custom>tfoot>tr>th, 
    .table-custom>tfoot>tr>td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap don't provide any variant of table-sm for small viewports. You need to target this with bootstrap (CSS) media query

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
 .table-custom th,
 .table-custom td {
     padding: .3em !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot ! I just noticed that I can find this out also using the Inspector in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, dev tools comes handy in these cases :)

Comment: One more beginner's question on this: I only got this to work when I added the .table-custom class to each of my th and td elements (it did not work when I added it directly on the table element). I assume this is being overwritten by Bootstrap if I apply it to the table element as I don't use other CSS styles there. Is there any other way to prevent that ? Just curious as applying it only to the table would be much more convenient.

Comment: Try `table.table.table-custom th` instead of `.table-custom th`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bootstrap built-in class "table-responsive",
like this,

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      ...
    </table>
</div>
```

it will work for you in mobile screens as a scrollable table.

Comment: I already show that I apply that in my question and it's not the answer to my question ?!